# Preferred way to set default application by content/MIME type from the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, preferences, launch-services

Per https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/9883/206073 , default file opening by content type should be set via `LSHandlers -> LSHandlerContentType` in `com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure` (via `defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist LSHandlers -array[-add]`). The format of `LSHandlerContentType` is in what is apparently the Mac's way of indicating MIME types, e.g., "public.css". (And I know that `defaults read /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist` can show how the Mac associates these content types to MIME types (and also how `UTTypeConformsTo` there will indicate a hierarchy between types).)

However, according to https://superuser.com/a/421865/156958 , content type can also be associated by setting `LSHandlers -> LSHandlerContentTag` with a MIME type (e.g., "text/css") and setting `LSHandlerContentTagClass` to "public.mime-type". I don't see any such settings in my own `defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist LSHandlers`, however.

I am unclear on which approach (`LSHandlerContentType` or `LSHandlerContentTag` (with `LSHandlerContentTagClass` of "public.mime-type")) is to be preferred (or which gets preference), or if there is any reason to use both.

As a bonus, I'd also be interested to know how `UTImportedTypeDeclarations`/`UTExportedTypeDeclarations` may fit into this (e.g., if these indications of third-party MIME types affects which of the two formats to use).

Comment: Asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979227/preferred-way-to-set-default-application-by-content-mime-type-from-the-command-l